# Difference between word stemming and depluralization

Tags: nlp, stemming, pluralize

In understanding string matching: What is the exact difference between *word stemming* and *depluralization?*

Or do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, **stemming** refers to the process of reducing a word to its stem. However, that may mean a number of different things. Most linguists differentiate between at least two ways of doing it:

1. Removing *grammatical*, but not *derivational* morphemes. Grammatical morphemes are components of the word that are related to its grammatical role in a particular sentence, e.g. *number*, *case*, *gender*, *tense*, *aspect* etc.
2. Removing *both* grammatical and derivational morphemes. Derivational morphemes are components of the word that are related to its derivation from another word, e.g. the "-er" in "worker" is related to how it is derived (or can be considered as derived) from "work".

Therefore, **depluralization**, which is a rather unusual term, but obviously refers to removing a plural morpheme (such as the "-s" at the end of "computers"), is **part of a kind of stemming**, specifically a part of the removal of grammatical (but not derivational) morphemes.

In **English**, the morphology of **nouns** is largely limited to plural ("computers") and genitive (second case, "computer's"), hence as far as English is concerned, depluralization may be seen as (almost) synonymous with (grammatical) stemming, at least to the extent that stemming is applied to *nouns*, and, to some degree, *adjectives*, (which it is e.g. in the context of information retrieval). However, wherever *verbs* are considered, *past tense*, *passive voice* and other inflectional forms are subject to stemming (but not to depluralization).

Furthermore, in languages other than English, even nouns may have a very rich morphology, including morphemes for such things as case, politeness level, or special kinds of plural (such as dual). And then, depluralization (if you want to use that term at all) would refer to only a very small part of the overall stemming process.

Another related term is **lemmatization**, which is often used synonymously with **stemming**. One distinction between the two that I found many people (including myself) to make is this:

- **Stemming** is used to refer to a **rule-based or machine-learning based** technique that removes parts of a word (mostly endings) that look like grammatical morphemes
- **Lemmatization** is used to refer to a process that does the same, but using an actual **dictionary** of the language to deal with highly irregular forms (such as the plural "women")

(But, again, not everyone will agree with this distinction.)

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. There are a few approaches to stemming a word, depluralization is one strategy.

just one quick example: a stemmer might stem "childish" into "child", or the word "stemmer" into "stem", while a depluralization algorithm will not.

Answer (score 1):

Stemming is converting multiple words with the same root to one word.
Ex. "cats", "catlike", "catty" to "cat"

Depluralization is converting plural words into singular.
Ex. "cats" to "cat"

Additional info for stemming and algorithms
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming#Algorithms